# iOS App auto create account on web service

Tags: ios, web-services

I Was wondering if anyone can tell me if this is possible. So.. I am just about to create my first iPhone app. I have my idea and everything is sketched out etc.. but then today I realised that I had not thought about all the features and their implementation properly. This could soon be a no win situation, so please help

Is it possible to create a username and password automatically upon first app opening? so the username and password is to be generated on the fly and then submitted to a web database.

I would also like it so that the user of the app could change this manually if they wished. but also so that if they viewed it on their other iDevices they could sync it up.

Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? Are you asking whether it's possible to generate a random string? (yes, that is perfectly possible)

Comment: whether its possible to generate a random string, store that on the device and webservice and allow user to change.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you could generate a random string to sign up a user for first time (backdoor guest account sort of speak), I've done it with one of my apps before (temporarily). However, you should consider baking a guest account feature into your remote server.